# Run this PHP file via Cron Job

Tags: scripting, cron, php

Here is the script:

---

```
<?php
//Create back files?
define('CREATE_BACKUPS', FALSE);

if (!is_dir($argv[1]))
{
   echo "You must enter a valid path such as /home/apresv/public_html or apresv/public_html for this script to function.\n";
   exit;
}

//Search the path for all php files, opening each one, and checking to see if it's infected

//First, get an array list of all valid .php files.


$files = listdir($argv[1]);
foreach ($files as $filename)
{
   //We only need to check php files, so we add that here
   if (file_extension($filename) == 'php')
   {
      //This is a php file so lets check it to see if it's infected.
      $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
      $backup = $contents;

      //There will always be 2 opening tags in an infected file and since the hack is always at the top, it's easiest to test for this right away.
      $test = between('<?php', '<?php', $contents);

      //This particular hack likes to use toolbarqueries so we test to see if our chunk is an infected chunk.  If your website uses this url somehow, then add extra if statements as necessary.
      if (after('toolbarqueries', $test))
      {
         //This chunk is infected.  So lets replace it and resave the file.
         $contents = str_replace('<?php'.$test.'<?php', '<?php', $contents);

         //Now save it! Woohoo!
         file_put_contents($filename, $contents);
         if (CREATE_BACKUPS)
         {
            file_put_contents($filename.'.orig', $backup);
         }

         echo "$filename has been cleaned.\n";
      }
   }
}

function after ($this, $inthat)
    {
        if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $this)))
        return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat,$this)+strlen($this));
    };

    function after_last ($this, $inthat)
    {
        if (!is_bool(strrevpos($inthat, $this)))
        return substr($inthat, strrevpos($inthat, $this)+strlen($this));
    };

    function before ($this, $inthat)
    {
        return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this));
    };

    function before_last ($this, $inthat)
    {
        return substr($inthat, 0, strrevpos($inthat, $this));
    };

    function between ($this, $that, $inthat)
    {
     return before($that, after($this, $inthat));
    };

    function between_last ($this, $that, $inthat)
    {
     return after_last($this, before_last($that, $inthat));
    };

    // USES
    function strrevpos($instr, $needle)
    {
        $rev_pos = strpos (strrev($instr), strrev($needle));
        if ($rev_pos===false) return false;
        else return strlen($instr) - $rev_pos - strlen($needle);
    };

    function listdir($dir='.') {
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        return false;
    }

    $files = array();
    listdiraux($dir, $files);

    return $files;
}

function listdiraux($dir, &$files) {
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        $filepath = $dir == '.' ? $file : $dir . '/' . $file;
        if (is_link($filepath))
            continue;
        if (is_file($filepath))
            $files[] = $filepath;
        else if (is_dir($filepath))
            listdiraux($filepath, $files);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

function file_extension($filename)
{
   $info = pathinfo($filename);
   return $info['extension'];
} 
?>
```

---

When I try to run this via a cron, I get the output 
"You must enter a valid path such as /home/apresv/public_html or apresv/public_html for this script to function.

What do I need to do to get this to run via a CRON JOB?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it run from the command-line? What is your crontab line?

Comment: You need to give a parameter with the path which files should be backuped. you can see this in line 3.

Comment: What would that look like?  This is a standard webhosting directory path environment... 

The cron line looks like this currently


'0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/apresv/fix_hack.php'

Answer (score 0):

The basic to execute a script with CRON is to make the file executable, talking about a `php` file you must give the file the path where is the interpreter command, this is called `shebang` (read more about in [here](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang)) and must be placed at the very top of the script.

So you must do the following

```
$ chmod +x script.php
$ sed -i '1 i\#!/usr/bin/php' script.php #This is to insert the shebang
```

So you can configure the CRON

```
$ crontab -e
* * * * * /path/to/script.php
```

**NOTE:** Of course you have to be sure your script works.

Comment: What would that look like? This is a standard webhosting directory path environment... The cron line looks like this currently '0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/apresv/fix_hack.php' –

Comment: @dprestia Ok, that means that you want to execute your script every day at 00:00:00 hour right? ddi you execute `crontab -e` to configure or how did you insert that line?

Comment: Webhost Crontab Tool...   The timing at this point isn't the issue - its getting the script past the "you must enter a valid path...." message

Comment: @dprestia Do you have access to the command-line of the server? Execute `$ crontab -e` and remove the `/usr/bin/php` path from the cron so it looks like `0 0 * * * /home/apresv/fix_hack.php`

Comment: i do thru the cron tab tool - i removed the /usr/bin/php as suggested...  i now get the following response ..."/bin/sh: /home/apresv/fix_hack.php: usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Comment: @dprestia Please read again the answer below, YOU MUST INSERT THE SHEBANG AT THE FIRST LINE `#!/usr/bin/php` OF YOUR SCRIPT. ALSO YOU MUST MAKE THE FILE `executable`

Comment: I believe i have done those things . the first line within the script file is #!/usr/bin/php ... and the file itself is 0777 for permissions making it executable(?)  if this is incorrect i appreciate your assistance and definitely your patience as i am not a programmer/coder.  Thank you!

Comment: @dprestia Ok I understand, please tell me, do you have access to the linux/unix server where the script is located?

Comment: I have access to it thru the CPANEL (Webhosting Access)